# Spring boot Jdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I have a doubt of how the spring boot JDBC template works. I have read the documentation , but could not understand clearly :( When does the template opens connection , when does it gets closed . How does the transactions are handled . Does it gets opened and closed for every query execution ?

Comment: There is no easy answer... It basically all depends, if you have transaction management set up or not. If not a connection will be opened (and closed) for each action, if you have you have 1 connection opened at the start of the transaction and closed after the transaction ends.

Answer (score 2):

> When does the template opens connection, when does it gets closed

For building JdbcTemplate you should specify the JDBC DataSource to obtain connections from:

```
public JdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource)
```

Or:

```
public JdbcTemplate()
JdbcAccessor.setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource)
```

Conclusively, `JdbcTemplate` works with this `DataSource`.

`DataSource`, depending on the implementation, may return new standard `Connection` objects that are not pooled or `Connection` objects that participate in connection pooling which can be an be recycled.

`JdbcTemplate` has pooled connections and releases them back to DataSource.

> How does the transactions are handled

`JdbcTemplate` relies on database transactions.
If you want to operate transactions on service layer/business logic you need transaction management. 
The simplest way is to annotate services with `@Transactional` or use `org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate`.